# How to edit an object property within an array of objects using PHP?

Tags: php

In the code below, I create an object instance $T, give its properties values, and add it to my array of objects called $teacherObjArray. However, where I'm having trouble is if the object instance already exists (this is checked by the teacherExists() function)... how does does the program know which $T object I am accessing? In other words, How can I program it to where it UPDATES the CORRECT within the array of objects? My definition of correct is where $teacherName is the same as object property LName. I appreciate the help :)

```
function teacherExists($teacherObjArray, $teacherName) {
    foreach ($teacherObjArray as $Teacher) {
        if ($Teacher->LName == $teacherName) return true; //can i return index here? 
    }
    return false;
}
while(sizeOf($r) > 0) 
{
     if (!teacherExists($teacherObjArray, $teacherName)) {
        $T = new Teacher($teachernName, $teacherMaxLoad, $classPeriod); 
        $T->LName = $teacherName;
        $T->MaxLoad = $teacherMaxLoad; 
        $T->addPeriod($classPeriod);  
        array_push($teacherObjArray, $T); 

        //create course object

        $C = new Course($courseNumber, $courseName, $teacherName, $classPeriod); 
        $C->CourseNumber=$courseNumber;
        $C->CourseName=$courseName; 
        $C->CourseTeacher=$teacherName;
        $C->CoursePeriod=$classPeriod; 

        maintenance($r, $teacherName, $classPeriod, $cn); 
    }
        //updates already existing object in array of objects
    elseif (teacherExists($teacherObjArray, $teacherName)) 
    {
        //get teacher object where its LName property is equal to $teacherName 

        $T->addPeriod($classPeriod);
        maintenance($r, $teacherName, $classPeriod, $cn); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `$r` represent?

Comment: $r is the array I have created using mysqli_fetch_array, it is essentially taking a query and representing it in an array form.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite `teacherExists` to return the index of the found value, or `false` when not found:

```
function teacherExists($teacherObjArray, $teacherName) {
    foreach ($teacherObjArray as $key => $Teacher) {
        if ($Teacher->LName == $teacherName) return $key; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then you can rewrite your `if` clause to check that the return value is `false`:

```
if (($key = teacherExists($teacherObjArray, $teacherName)) === false) {
```

and your `elseif` clause simply becomes:

```
else
{
    //get teacher object where its LName property is equal to $teacherName 
    $T = $teacherObjArray[$key];
    $T->addPeriod($classPeriod);
    maintenance($r, $teacherName, $classPeriod, $cn); 
}
```

Note that since you call

```
maintenance($r, $teacherName, $classPeriod, $cn);
```

at the end of both the `if` and `else` clauses, you could move it after the `if` block.

Comment: Another thing to add is that the `maintenance` function can be called after the if/else statement.